# Loading content when switching tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to recreate a tab like this in the below link so when u for instance click on another tab it remove the content and loading the new with a loading image. In below link try and click under 21 in the tab and u see it slides the content out and show loading image and then show the new content? How can i achieve similar effect?

So far i've tried by using pure css/html tabs however it seems like it cant be done that way.

http://themes.goodlayers.com/realsoccer/fixtures-results/

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery Tabs 
"A single content area with multiple panels, each associated with a header in a list." :

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/